# Calculate remaining expiration time and refresh token

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, setinterval

I need to refresh the Spotify token every one hour in a React app (Spotify token is valid for 1hr). I know the below method using the **useEffect** hook with **setInteral**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    //call api logic
  }, 3600);
  return () => clearInterval(interval); 
}, [user])
```

But when the app is closed and opened again, it again makes a new request to get the token (even the old token is valid). So I am trying to implement based on the remaining expiration time the API needs to called for fetching new token. How to achieve this functionality.

I also created a function that calculates the remaining expiration time when the exp time is passed

```
export const calculateRemainingExpirationTime = expirationTime => {
  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  const newExpirationTime = new Date(expirationTime).getTime()
  const remainingTime = newExpirationTime - currentTime
  return remainingTime; // in milliseconds
};
```

So when the page is reloaded, I need to calculate the remaining expiration time and then based on that API needs to be called and after that every 1Hr the API needs to be called to get the new token.

**I need the following functionality to be achieved**

1. When page reloaded calculate remining time and call API based on that remaining time
2. For every 1Hr API needs to called

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the `expiration time`  somewhere in `localStorage` or with `Redux-persist`

```
//This interval only executes if user have'nt closed the app
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    //call api logic
    // Write the expiration to local storage
     localStorage.setItem("expir",value)
  }, 3600);
  return () => clearInterval(interval); 
}, [user])
```

```
//Take the expiration time that was written/stored in local storage

 React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    const getToken = () => {
      if (mounted) {
        const expirationtime = localStorage.getItem("expir");
        if (new Date() > new Date(Number(expirationtime))) {
          // expired , get new token
        } else {
          // existing token
        }
      }
    };
    getToken();
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [user]);
```

Comment: yes I am storing the exp time in local storage. Consider the if block in your answer 
`if (new Date() > new Date(Number(expirationtime))) {// expired , get new token}`
My doubt is where to place the set interval code ?, If I place it inside this **if block** then I need to set the interval for every 1-hr. Now consider the else block and in this case there is still time left for the token to expire (for example consider 10 min is there), so after this 10 min it should get the new token. My question is how many set interval I need to use for both cases and where exactly to place  setinterval

Comment: also when the page is reloaded the exp time also reduces and token should be fetched on that reduced exp time. And after that every 1hr it should fetch (if page is not reloaded). This is where I am stuck

Comment: Final code
`useEffect(() => {
    async function updateTokenExpirationTime() {
      if (user) {
        const storedSpotifyExpirationDate = await AsyncStorage.getItem('spotifytokenExp',);const remainingSpotifyTime = calculateRemainingExpirationTime(storedSpotifyExpirationDate,);
        if (remainingSpotifyTime <= 60000) {//less than or equal to 1 min (60000 seconds)  await refreshTokenHandler();}else{spotifyLogoutTimer = setInterval(           refreshTokenHandler,remainingSpotifyTime, );}}}
    updateTokenExpirationTime(); return () => {clearInterval(spotifyLogoutTimer); };}, [user]);`